# Adding a 'Where' clause in a lamba expression?

Tags: c#-4.0, entity-framework-4

I want to select distinct values for a column 'language', where the 'project_ID' is equal to a specific value, from a table called 'screenshots' in my database.

I know how to do this (but it gives me the distinct languages in the entire 'screenshots' table):

```
var result = db.screenshots.Select(m => m.language).Distinct();
```

How can I add a where clause to my query to ensure that I only get the distinct language values where the project_ID of that column is equal to a specific value?

In plain old SQL this would be the query I want to achieve:

```
select distinct language from screenshots
where projects_ID=31
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you want to apply `where` clause, and then `select distinct`. Here it is in code

```
db.screenshots.Where(m => m.ProjectId == 31).Select(m => m.language).Distinct();
```

Comment: That works great - thank you. I'll accept as the answer when I can (in around 8 minutes).